# Validating if an radio button has been checked using jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, for-loop

Below I have an example of radio button group which I am trying to validate whether one has been checked or not, the reason I am using the `.each()` function is to add in additional inputs so the function can loop through them. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LSG5/)

**HTML**

```
<table class="application entitlement">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><label for="entitlement">Yes</label><input type="radio" value="yes" name="entitlement"></td>
        <td><label for="entitlement">No</label><input type="radio" value="no" name="entitlement"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a href="#" class="send-application">Submit Application</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('body').on('click', '.send-application', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var isFormValid = true;
        $('input[name=entitlement]').each(function(index, elem){
            if (!$(this).is(':checked').val()) {
                $(this).css({'box-shadow': '0 0 5px rgba(255,0,0,0.4)'});
                isFormValid = false;
            } else {
                $(this).css({'box-shadow': 'none'});
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a flaw in your logic. `isFormValid` will always be set to `false` as you will never be able to check all buttons in the radio group.

Instead of looping over each one, just check the entire collection to see if any are checked or not:

```
var $radioButtons = $('input[name=entitlement]');

if ( !$radioButtons.filter(':checked').length ) {
    isFormValid = false;
    $radioButtons.css('box-shadow', '0 0 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)');
} else {
    $radioButtons.css('box-shadow', 'none');
}
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LSG5/2/)

Comment: What if there was two types of radio buttons? one called `entitlement` the other called `declaration`

Comment: Presumably you'd want to check that one is checked in each group, in which case you'd need to check each collection separately, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xC42m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
```

instead of:

```
if (!$(this).is(':checked').val()) {
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LSG5/1/)**

---

Based on your comment, you can use **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter)** instead of `.each()`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.send-application', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$('input[name=entitlement]').filter(':checked').length) {
        $(this).css({
            'box-shadow': '0 0 5px rgba(255,0,0,0.4)'
        });
        isFormValid = false;
    } else {
        $(this).css({
            'box-shadow': 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LSG5/4/)**

Comment: Thanks Felix, this still flags up one of the inputs as invalid if one of the inputs in the example is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code remove `.val()`

```
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
```

`$(this).is(':checked')` returns either true or false,if false your below code will work and add box shadow to the unchecked checkbox

Answer (score 0):

when you check a radio button, `entitlement` is automatically assigned the value of the selected radio button. So you can just check the value of the input using `$(this).val()`.